# forkjointask.java invokeall(t1,t2) method,this method source why not use double join() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

source:

```
public static void invokeAll(ForkJoinTask<?> t1, ForkJoinTask<?> t2) {
    t2.fork();
    t1.invoke();
    t2.join();
}
```

why not use :

```
public static void invokeAll(ForkJoinTask<?> t1, ForkJoinTask<?> t2) {
    t1.fork();
    t2.fork();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: Why create two extra threads when only one extra thread is enough?

Comment: why one thread enough?Can you teach me the principles? I see other data, introduce the wording is optimal, but I do not know what way through optimization.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation for `ForkJoinTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html):

> Method [`invoke()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#invoke()) is semantically equivalent to `fork(); join()` but always attempts to begin execution in the current thread.

So the version with `invoke()` is doing the same thing as your version, but instead of passing both jobs off to two different threads, it's passing `t2` off to another thread and trying to handle `t1` itself. That's less passing around, and less threads involved.

In your version, the current thread has nothing to do but wait once it `fork()`s both tasks.